# Iterating through rows of a data grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

how to iterate through every row of data grid view in WPF

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView dr in grid.Items)
{
    string a = dr[0].ToString();
    MessageBox.show(a);
}
```

here I try to read all the values of first column!

It gives error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Test.exe
>       Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

How can I resolve this. please any one help me.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the data type of `dr[0]`? `Nullable`? Maybe you should check is it `null` before call the `ToString()`

Answer (score 5):

[`Grid.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection used to generate the content of the `ItemsControl`, cast to `DataRowView` is invalid. Which is cauing an exception in this case.

What you need is...

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in grid.ItemsSource)
{
     MessageBox.Show(dr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, here is a small mistake in your code `MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());`